# Differential of $g^{-1}.p$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups

Let $M$ be a manifold and $G$ be a Lie Group acting smoothly on $M$ on the right and on the left.

Set $f:M \times G \rightarrow M$ by $f(p,g)=g^{-1}.p$.

If we denote the right action by $p.g=\mu(p,g)$, we know that $$d_{(p,g)}\mu(X,(L_g)_*(Y))=(r_g)_*(X)+\left. \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \right|_{t=0}((p.g).e^{tY})$$
where $r_g:M\rightarrow M$ is given by $r_g(p)=p.g$

Is there a similar expression to $d_{(p,g)} f$ ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be
$
d_{(p.g)}f(X,d_eL_g(Y)) = d_pl_{g^{-1}}(X) + \frac{d}{dt}\big\vert_{t=0}(e^{-tY}\cdot (g^{-1}\cdot p))
$ (I'm replacing your use of $(\cdot)_*$ by the derivative map notation for consistency).

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it.